# Underline Text CSS Gap

Tags: html, css

I want my text to be underlined when it's active but when I did it looks like this:

[image: image 1]

I just only want the text to get underlined, if I used `text-decoration:underline` it underline the word but the I don't know how to make a gap between the text and the underline. I added new class `.currents`.

Here is my code:

```html
<header id="header" class="transparent-header" data-sticky-class="not-dark">
  <div id="header-wrap" style="height:180px;">
    <!-- Primary Navigation
============================================= -->
    <nav id="primary-menu" class="style-2 center">
      <div id="primary-menu-trigger">
        <i class="icon-reorder"></i>
      </div>
      <div style="text-align:center">
        <ul class="one-page-menu" data-easing="easeInOutExpo" data-speed="1250" data-offset="65">
          <li>
            <a href="index.html"><div>Home</div></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="about.html"><div>WHO WE ARE</div></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="products.html"><div>WHAT WE TRADE</div></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="services.html"><div>SERVICES</div></a>
          </li>
          <li class="currents">
            <a href="logistic.html"><div>LOGISTICS</div></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="contact.html"><div>CONTACT</div></a>
          </li> 
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav><!-- #primary-menu end -->
    <br>
  </div>
</header><!-- #header end -->
```

CSS:

```css
.currents {    
  height: 3em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid ;
  /* margin-bottom: 5px;*/      
}
```

Here is the working jsfiddle. Thanks in advance

https://jsfiddle.net/light22/atzL4ahu/#&togetherjs=eLF0v1iEs8

Comment: `Here is the working jsfiddle` forgotten?

Comment: @MoshFeu https://jsfiddle.net/light22/atzL4ahu/#&togetherjs=eLF0v1iEs8

Answer (score 2):

You can use `border-bottom` (instead of `text-decoration:underline`) and `padding-bottom` to achieve your wish.

Like this:

```css
a {
  text-decoration:none;  
  display:inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

.gap {
  padding-bottom:15px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">without gap</a>
<a href="#" class="gap">with gap</a>
```

Comment: Accept this as the answer by clicking the checkmark below the voting arrows.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the text in a `<span>` tag. Here's a working JSFiddle demonstrating this.

https://jsfiddle.net/j7wo5pxx/

Comment: Mosh Fue's answer also works, and should be the accepted answer. It's a simpler solution which doesn't make use of the extra markup. I answered with this only as an alternative.